# Whats the difference between enzyme find() and findWhere()?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, enzyme

Is there any difference between the return from find() and findWhere() ?

I was trying to get a prop that returns an array from a component that I got using find() but then I get this from TypeScript *Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)*

```
const wrapper = mount(<Component />)
const a = wrapper.find('[name='componentName']')
expect(a.prop('someProp')[0].value).toBe('someValue')
```

So instead of using wrapper.find() I'm using wrapper.findWhere() and it works. So, could someone know the difference between these methods ? I went to enzyme documentation and both said to return a *ReactWrapper*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify which line do you get that Typescript error? It would be helpful if you could provide the full stack trace.

One thing that I've noticed in your code that you are using 4 single-quote characters and I don't think it is valid. You might consider changing to this:

```
const a = wrapper.find("[name='componentName']")
```

I believe the docs has described the differences. The difference relies on their arguments. Note that `selector` means [enzyme selectors](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html).

[find(selector) => ReactWrapper](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html)

> Finds every node in the render tree of the current wrapper that matches the provided selector.

[.findWhere(fn) => ReactWrapper](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/findWhere.html)

> Finds every node in the render tree that returns true for the provided predicate function.

Comment: Hi, thanks! The Typescript error is when I'm trying to get "a.prop('someProp')[0].value", but only when I get 'a' using find(). When I use findWhere, it's just work fine.

Comment: Could you provide the code using `find` vs `findWhere` and the full stack trace? One possible cause I could think of may rely on the type definition of the library.

Comment: I don't see type definitions in Enzyme itself, only in [definitely-typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/enzyme/index.d.ts) repo. And there `find()` and `findWhere` looks equal in return type(to me)

Comment: If that's the case I think we should take a look at @user3886186 code and the error stack trace